# How to filter value if i have a string which is comma seprated

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an index which in which there is a property name JobProvince and I need to filter the record. I have a string

`string str = "Friesland,Gelderland"`

I am looking for the record which JobProvince is "Gelderland" and I am trying to do with

`q.MatchPhrase(c => c.Field(p => p.JobProvincie)                                                                                                                                                                       .Query(nq => nq.Terms(t => t.Field(tf => tf.JobProvincie.First()).Terms(JobProvinciefacets.Split(',')))))`

but not getting the result. How can I do this, please help.

Comment: Could you please show a succinct, but complete example of how you're indexing and how you're performing the search. Without these, it's difficult to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer by using

```
q.MatchPhrase(a => a.Field(af => af.JobCity).Query(searchLocationLowerCase))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Either convert comma separated values to array while indexing or use comma tokenizer while indexing, post it you will be able to search document using normal term fields

"settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": ","
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comma Tokenizer [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html) for reference